# Why isn't glDrawElements coloring my circle?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, opengl-4

I'm learning opengl and trying to draw a colored indexed circle using glDrawEmelents, but for some reason it does not work. The circle appears white, despite the specified color being red.

```
GLuint vShader = 0;
GLuint fShader = 0;
static const GLchar* fragText[] = {
    "#version 450 core \n"
    "in vec3 icolor;\n"
    "out vec3 ocolor;\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "   ocolor = icolor;\n"
    "}\n"
};

static const GLchar* vertText[] = {
    "#version 450 core \n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
    "layout (location = 1) in vec3 icolor;\n"

    "out vec3 fcolor;\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "   fcolor = icolor;\n"
    "   gl_Position = position;\n"
    "}\n"
};

vShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
fShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

glShaderSource(vShader, 1, vertText, NULL);

glCompileShader(vShader);

GLint status;
glGetShaderiv(vShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);

if (status != GL_TRUE) {
    printf("v bust");
}

glShaderSource(fShader, 1, fragText, NULL);

glCompileShader(fShader);

if (status != GL_TRUE) {
    printf("f bust");
}


GLuint programID = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(programID, vShader);
glAttachShader(programID, fShader);

glLinkProgram(programID);



int size = (sizeof(circleVerts) / sizeof(glm::vec4));
//printf("size:%d\n", size);
circleVerts[0] = glm::vec4(0, 0, 0, 1.0f);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    float heading = 360.f * ((float)i / (float)(size));
    heading = glm::radians(heading);
    circleVerts[i] = glm::vec4(glm::cos(heading), glm::sin(heading), 0, 1);
    //printf("%d:(%f,%f,%f,%f)\n", i, circleVerts[i].x, circleVerts[i].y, circleVerts[i].z, circleVerts[i].w);
    //printf("Heading:%f\n", heading);
}

//printf("size:%d\n", (sizeof(circleIndices) / sizeof(GLuint)));

for (int i = 0; i + 2 < size; ++i) {
    int index = i * 3;
    circleIndices[index] = 0;
    circleIndices[index + 1] = i + 1;
    circleIndices[index + 2] = i + 2;
    //printf("i=%d,Indices:%d,%d,%d\n", i, circleIndices[i], circleIndices[i + 1], circleIndices[i + 2]);
}




GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(circleVerts), circleVerts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

int size = sizeof(circleColor) / sizeof(glm::vec3);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    circleColor[i] = glm::vec3(1.0f, 0, 0);
}


GLuint cbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &cbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(circleColor), circleColor, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

GLuint ibo;
glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(circleIndices), circleIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC1_ALPHA);
glUseProgram(programID);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 90, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

I've edited the frag shader to the following. Even with this shader it still appears white. I initially expected something to be wrong with the color buffer, but something appears to be wrong with the frag shader.

```
static const GLchar* fragText[] = {
    "#version 450 core \n"
    "in vec3 icolor;\n"
    "out vec4 color;\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "   color = vec4(1,0,0,1);\n"
    "}\n"
};
```

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

The shader cannot link because there is no fragment shader input for the vertex shader output `fcolor`.
The output of a shader stage is linked to the input of the next shader stage by its name (except when you use a layout qualifier). See [interface matching rules between shader stages.](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Interface_matching)

Rename the framgen shader input from `icolor` to `fcolor`:

```c
#version 450 core
in vec3 fcolor;
out vec4 ocolor;
void main(void)
{
    ocolor = vec4(fcolor, 1.0);
}
```

---

Additionally there is an issue in your blend function. Most likely you wanted to use `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA` instead of `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC1_ALPHA`:

<s>`glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC1_ALPHA);`</s>

```cpp
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Comment: renaming icolor to fcolor in the fragment shader did not work.

Comment: Did you try `ocolor = vec4(fcolor, 1.0);`

Comment: Yes, no change.

Comment: It would appear so. At the end of my question I  mention that not even assigning a constant value to the fragment shader out color variable worked. Maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: @DohnJoe `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC1_ALPHA` -> `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA`